# why am i not being able to print spaces between the two strings using System.out.println?

Tags: java

The question given asked us to print characters at even and odd postions seperately with two spaces between them ,i was able to find the strings but the spaces between them aren't printing.

````
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            String s=sc.next();
            String temp1="";
            String temp2="";
            for(int j=0;j<s.length();j+=2)//getting characters at even locations
            {
                temp1+=s.charAt(j);
            }
            for(int j=1;j<s.length();j+=2)
            {
                temp1+=s.charAt(j);//getting characters at odd locations 
            }
            System.out.println(temp1+"  "+temp2);
        }
    }
}```


input as follows :
2
Hacker
Rank

output gained as:
Hceakr  
Rnak  

expected output as:
Hce akr
Rn ak
````

Comment: Typo. The second loop; `for(int j=1;j<s.length();j+=2)
            {
                temp1+=s.charAt(j);//getting characters at odd locations 
            }` should be `for(int j=1;j<s.length();j+=2)
            {
                temp2+=s.charAt(j);//getting characters at odd locations 
            }`

Answer (score 1):

You you are not assigning odd character to temp2 so your temp2 is empty and `System.out.println(temp1+" "+temp2);` is printing temp1(Which contains even position's characters followed by odd position's characters) value and space,  here is working code

```java
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            String s=sc.next();
            String temp1="";
            String temp2="";
            for(int j=0;j<s.length();j+=2)//getting characters at even locations
            {
                temp1+=s.charAt(j);
            }
            for(int j=1;j<s.length();j+=2)
            {
                temp2+=s.charAt(j);//getting characters at odd locations 
            }

            System.out.println(temp1+" "+temp2);
        }
    }
```

**Change** 
Actually in your code . 
`temp1+=s.charAt(j);//getting characters at odd locations` 
Suppose to be

`temp2+=s.charAt(j);//getting characters at odd locations`

Answer (score 0):

Use the temp2 variable inside the second for loop instead of temp1 variable, in the code you posted above you didn't stored anything in the temp2 so it prints an empty string in the output.